# UUID check using python UUID module changes UUID

Tags: python, uuid

I've run into this odd behaviour when I use the `UUID()` function from the python `uuid` module to check one of our test uuids.

`from uuid import UUID
uuid1 = UUID('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', version=1)
print uuid1
00000000-0000-1000-8000-000000000000`

without the version it works as expected

`uuid0 = UUID('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
print uuid0
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`

Is this expected behavour?  Are there any other side effects that I need to worry about?

Is there a safer or better way to test uuids in python I should use instead of the `UUID()` function or am I misusing this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From code comment

> ```
>  The 'version' argument is optional; if given, the resulting
>         UUID will have its variant and version set according to RFC 4122,
>         overriding the given 'hex', 'bytes', 'bytes_le', 'fields', or 'int'.
> ```

[RFC versions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.1.3)

To generate uuid you can use one of following functions depending on uuid type

```
uuid1(), uuid3(), uuid4(), uuid5()
```

And as you already know UUID() to parse UUID into object

[Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/uuid.html)

Comment: Thanks for posting the comment!  I'd tested other versions and read through the RFC, and so suspected something like this, but hadn't gone through the code. I would have been happier if it had failed the check with a `ValueError` as it does for other incorrect formatting, but alas.